# Why is there only one compression ring per groove in a piston?

Tags: engine-theory

Why is there only one compression ring per groove in a piston?

Two half sized rings in the same groove would take up the same amount of space as one piston ring but if you offset the rings gaps, in theory, you'd get effectively no blow by.

I found a patent for the idea [freepatentsonline.com/5261362.html](https://freepatentsonline.com/5261362.html) but it doesn't put much effort in explaining potential drawbacks.

I figure if this were a good idea everyone would be doing it so I have to be missing something.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any hard data on this, but I would think the *main issue* with doing this is the mechanical complication of it. Realize piston rings aren't exactly flat. They have a small amount of twist to them (twist from inside, as in next to the piston, to the outside which rides on the cylinder wall). Getting two rings to sit together, riding surface to surface, is not going to be an easy feat. Yes, it could be done, but to what effect? The complication does not outweigh return.

Things to consider:

First, this is the reason there are usually two compression rings at the top of the piston. Most diesel engines have three compression rings which aid in the production of compression during the compression stroke. When you put piston rings together on a piston, you place the end gap at different orientation (called "clocking the ring"). This nearly in and of itself eliminates blow by in most engines ... at least until there is enough wear on the rings for those gaps to enlarge.

Secondly, there are aftermarket rings which have a zero ring gap (such as [Total Seal](http://www.totalseal.com/) - no affiliation). These rings do exactly what you are talking about, such as improving compression and thus producing more power with less blow by. The thing is, these being aftermarket have a marked price increase over what stock piston rings would cost. While it isn't a huge cost to racing teams who are looking for every last ounce of power out of their engine, putting these into a mass marketed engine line would cost a manufacturer (potentially) millions of dollars to implement. When what they are using now works pretty good, the cost is not worth the return.

Also a consideration, the thicker the piston ring, the more drag there is on the cylinder walls. Piston rings used in production vehicles today are considerably thinner than the rings used of old. For instance, Chevrolet LS1 engines use compression rings which are 1.5mm in thickness. The Gen1 small block Chevy engines were 5/64ths (or 1.984375mm). The newer rings are approximately 3/4ths the thickness of the old ones. When you consider in a V8 engine there are two of each of these rings per cylinder and eight cylinders, there's a huge difference in the amount of drag. Even with this less drag, there is no loss of compression in comparison. They just work more efficiently. This more than makes up the difference in what you are talking about in the loss of power due to compression differences.

Like I said to start, there's several reasons for manufacturers to not utilize this technology and only one reason to use them. Hopefully this gives you a better understanding of the situation.

Comment: I'd add one other thing. Some rings, like keystone, are meant to flex as the cylinder moves. Two rings on top of each other would interfere with the flexing.

Comment: @vini_i - I'd agree for the most part, except for two things: 1) the keystone/flex action is by design. I was trying to be more general. 2) The cylinder doesn't move ... the piston does ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Forget everything that those people said. Aside from it being half rings, you use full size rings and put the gaps of 180 apart, this is called the twin ring setup, it's used in special applications and it's very effective to increase the compression ratio and lower the wear and tear on the wrist pins and connecting rods along with the cylinder walls and rings because the double rings give it more width to stabilize the angled thrust of the rod & crank. Eliminates the middle ring.  Only 2 grooves are necessary.  Try it yourself with a lawn mower keep in mind the groove shouldn't be double the size. It should be slightly larger than double to allow for twisting and make sure your chamfer is facing upward on the top and down on the bottom. If you crosshatch the cylinder walls at a 45 ° angle make sure the Rings will not rotate and lock into each other, this will be catastrophic!